# Short transit time in Frankfurt

Tags: transit, short-connections, fra

I'm flying from Reykjavík to Ljubljana via Frankfurt. I will have checked luggage. Is a transit time of 45 minutes enough?

Comment: Same question as always: single ticket or two separate tickets? If the latter, definitely not.

Comment: Also which airlines? If you have to change terminals, you need even more time. But also a walk from the highest A gate to a C gate can easily take 20 minutes.

Comment: @dunni It is intra-Schengen, so no need to walk to C.

Answer (score 5):

It's enough if you are traveling on one ticket, issued by one airline, as the airline has the responsibility of making sure there is sufficient and reasonable time for you to make the connection, and to compensate and make alternate arrangements otherwise.

If you bought two tickets on two separate airlines, then 45 minutes is not enough, since you'll have to collect and re-check your bags and the airline responsible for the second flight will say that it was your responsibility to get to the airport on time.

Answer (score -1):

Better always have not less than an hour between the flights. Flights can be delayed for no obvious reasons and these 20 minutes can turn out to be crucial. And there's no use telling people in the queue that you'll be late for your next flight because everyone is in a hurry. I wouldn't recommend a 45 minute transit even if you have no checked luggage and only one ticket.

Comment: Which queues?  It is an intra-Schengen flight, so there will be no queue in Frankfurt except for boarding.

Comment: Actually, on occasions when I have been in a huge hurry, I've pushed through queues apologising profusely, with no problems at all. People understand that, sometimes, people get delayed by circumstances beyond their control. But I agree that a 45-minute transit is asking for a missed connection and, even if you make the connection, there's a good chance your bags will be on the next plane.